# Craft 3: How to get Volume by handle?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, services

How can I get the details of an asset volume in Craft 3, if I only know the handle?

I found the Volumes and the Assets service, but I believe none of them provides a method for that purpose. The only thing I found was this:

```
Craft::$app->getVolumes()->getVolumeById($id)
```

But how do I get the id? I do not want to iterate over `getAllVolumes()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/7b31701c9a139bb8078563c86a0698d7f68e35a0), there is a `Craft::$app->getVolumes()->getVolumeByHandle($handle)` method you can call.

Comment: Since Craft 4 uses a total renewed system called FileSystems instead of volumes. Whats the equivalent of this in Craft 4?